# Why Visual Studio Code always break on start when debugging Next.js Full stack?

Tags: visual-studio-code, next.js, phpstorm, vscode-debugger

I'm debugging a Next.js 13 application using the following `.vscode/launch.json` file:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "compounds": [
      {
        "name": "Compound",
        "configurations": [],
        "stopAll": false
      }
    ],
    "configurations": [
      {
        "name": "Next.js: debug server-side",
        "type": "node-terminal",
        "request": "launch",
        "command": "npm run dev",
        "stopOnEntry": false
      },
      {
        "name": "Next.js: debug client-side",
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "url": "http://localhost:3000",
        "stopOnEntry": false
      },
      {
        "name": "Next.js: debug full stack",
        "type": "node-terminal",
        "request": "launch",
        "command": "npm run dev",
        "serverReadyAction": {
          "pattern": "started server on .+, url: (https?://.+)",
          "uriFormat": "%s",
          "action": "debugWithChrome"
        },
        "stopOnEntry": false
      }
    ]
  }
```

However, every time I debug on the "Next.js: debug full stack" option, it stops on the first file (.next/server/app...) after every refresh.

Although the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging) says stopOnEntry is accepted, vscode, says its not.
[image: vs code saying stopOnEntry is not allowed]

Perhaps I'm using it in the wrong place.
**How can I make Visual Studio code does not stop on entry?**

**Update**
I can confirm the same issue happen when Debugging on PhpStorm. Is it a Next.js bug?

Comment: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/31382

Comment: @Mahantesh.N.Hadimani. not really the same issue, I guess. I'm able to attach the breakpoint, but it is annoying that after doing that, I get 3 or 4 files opened by debugger, on folders that were supposed to be ignored, and that I don't have any breakpoints. It slows me down a lot.

Comment: oh k. I am also not getting...

Answer (score -2):

Try Using this:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "compounds": [
    {
      "name": "Compound",
      "configurations": [],
      "stopAll": false
    }
  ],
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Next.js: debug server-side",
      "type": "node-terminal",
      "request": "launch",
      "command": "npm run dev",
      "stopOnEntry": false
    },
    {
      "name": "Next.js: debug client-side",
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "url": "http://localhost:3000",
      "stopOnEntry": false
    },
    {
      "name": "Next.js: debug full stack",
      "type": "node-terminal",
      "request": "launch",
      "command": "node --inspect-brk $(which npm) run dev",
      "serverReadyAction": {
        "pattern": "started server on .+, url: (https?://.+)",
        "uriFormat": "%s",
        "action": "debugWithChrome"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Change it according to your requirements if you like.

Comment: I should try with the full stack option, right? I'm using Firefox, but the server wasn't even able to start with this config. Thanks for replying anyway.